# DJISDKManager.registerApp() crashes in some devices

Tags: dji-sdk

Description of the issues.
`DJISDKManager.registerApp()` ends up in crashing.

Steps to reproduce the bug or crash issues(It would be great if you can provide this)
App crashes when we try to register the app using `DJISDKManager.registerApp()` method

**DJI iOS SDK version**
DJI SDK 4.4

**DJI Product**
Mavic Pro

**iOS system version**
iOS 11.2.6

**iOS device type you are using**
iPad 5th generation

**Xcode version you are using**
Xcode Version 9.2 (9C40b)

Answer (score 0):

If this is a deadlock case (iOS killing the app for main thread locked) we are aware, fixed it and it's coming with 4.5 (in a few weeks).